# Call to a member function insert() on null. Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Hi everyone I am getting the following error when I submit my form for my CI 3 website:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on null

This error is occurring on line 20 which is:

```
$query =  $this->db->insert('temp_subscribed_users', $data);
```

Here is the full function:

```
public function add_temp_user($key)
{
    echo "hello";

    $data = array(


        'TEMP_EMAIL' => $this->input->post('email'),

        'TEMP_KEY' => $key

    );

    echo var_dump($data);

    $query =  $this->db->insert('temp_subscribed_users', $data);

    if($query)
    {

        return true;  
    }else{

        return false; 

    }
}
```

I am not sure what it means by null. The table name is correct and I did a var_dump to confirm that the array is being populated. I also made sure that I am getting into the function by echoing "hello" and it is outputting onto the page.

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Additional info: Running using XAMPP localhost.

Comment: You before load "db"?

Comment: @Deep yes, I have it autoloading the database library

Comment: You can also load the library manually before running the insert. You can use `$this->load->library('database');`

Answer (score 3):

load database and then call insert function. Codeigniter does not load database automatically for the performance issue.

```
$this->load->database();
$query =  $this->db->insert('temp_subscribed_users', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you're not utilizing the MVC model of codeigniter. Controller is for functions, Model is for the database connections.

First autoload your database, If not just put it in the code. But here is how it should look like.

**CONTROLLER FUNCTION**

```
public function add_temp_user($key)
{
    echo "hello";
    $this->load->model('MY_MODEL');
    //If you're not autoloading db include the next line
    //$this->load->library('database');
    $data = array(
        'TEMP_EMAIL' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'TEMP_KEY' => $key
    );

    echo var_dump($data);
    //If you confirmed the data var dumped

    $success = $this->MY_MODEL->insert_to_db($data);

    if($success == true)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    else
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public function insert_to_db($data)
{
  $query =  $this->db->insert('temp_subscribed_users', $data);
  //
  if($query)
  {
    return true;  
  }
  else
  {
    return false; 
  }
}
```

**Make sure the TEMP_EMAIL and TEMP_KEY are the columns in your database and temp_subscribed_users is your table name**

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve your problem by getting into the autoload.php in the config folder and add database on the array for libraries, like this: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check whether object is created or not.
2. Check that object is available in that class